# How to send an image file (png) to a REST API Post endpoint using Micronaut as Client

Tags: rest, kotlin, micronaut

I have this code as client for a POST API

```
@Produces("image/png")
@Post("/marketplaces/{marketplaceId}/banking/accreditation/holders/{holderId}/documents?type={type}")
fun saveIndividualDocumentHolder(
        @Header("Authorization") authorization: String,
        @PathVariable marketplaceId: String,
        @PathVariable holderId: String,
        @PathVariable type: String,
        @Body image: String
    ): HttpResponse<HolderDocumentResponse>
```

The API expects an image file as "image/png", "image/jpg". I am getting {415 Unsupported media type: text/plain"}

I send 'the file' using:

```
fun saveIndividualDocumentHolder(holderId: String, type: String,  file: MultipartBody): HttpResponse<HolderDocumentResponse> {
    val contentType = "image/png"


    val httpResponse = client.saveIndividualDocumentHolder(authorization, marketplaceId, holderId, type, file.toString())

    if (httpResponse.status != HttpStatus.CREATED) throw RuntimeException("HTTP status: ${httpResponse.status}" )
    val response = httpResponse.body()?: throw RuntimeException("No body")

   
    return httpResponse
}
```

I have picked the file from my 'internal endpoint' using MultipartBody. Then I convert this file to a String as Body request.
I am new to all these things, could you please elucidate?

Comment: You have `image` of type `String`.  Is that intentional?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown hi sir, no, I have just seen an example, I do admit that I did find it weird. I just copied and pasted that

Comment: What is it that you want to pass to the `saveIndividualDocumentHolder` method that contains the image data?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I wanna pass an image file to the API. API expects an image file

Comment: "I wanna pass an image file to the API" - Do you have a `byte` array or a `File` reference?  Something else?

Comment: No @JeffScottBrown... should I send to API, using my micronaut client, as a byte array?